# converting a string to binary number in python

Tags: python, binary

I want to convert a string consists of binary digits and convert that string into a binary number.

suppose, my input is "01001", this is in string format, i want to convert this to binary number format to perform various bit wise operations on that.

Comment: I am pretty sure there are plenty of answer to this question all around SO. Did you try searching a little?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the number to an [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and do bitwise operations, like this

```
my_int = int("01001", 2)
print my_int & 1   # 1
print my_int & 8   # 8
print my_int & 16  # 0
```